# How to make a button expand the length of an html table header?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a button that I put in a table `<th>` to expand the full width and height of the header column, even when a table cell in the same column is larger than the text. If I do, width 100% in css, then the button will just match the cell size, and then the title will extend beyond the button and header.

I am using the button so when the user click on it the column will sort.

This is my code just trying to do with width:

```
<th><button onclick="tableColumnSort(this)" style="width:100%">@descriptor.Name</button></th>
```

[image]

And this is how it looks without using width:

```
<th><button onclick="tableColumnSort(this)">@descriptor.Name</button></th>
```

[image]

Comment: Add scrollbar to table

Comment: @RAJNIK PATEL There is a scrollbar added, I am just showing a small snapshot of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change css of the clicked th with your js, with a low gray background (#ccc it's good) and change font-size a bit, 1 or 2px. TL;DR Change the frontend to show a more elegant th with the users interactions

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th onclick="tableColumnSort(this); changeTH(this);">
        shortHeader
      </th>
      <th onclick="tableColumnSort(this); changeTH(this);">
        veryLongLongHeader
      </th>
      <th onclick="tableColumnSort(this); changeTH(this);">
        header
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th onclick="tableColumnSort(this); changeTH(this);">
        shortHeader
      </th>
      <th onclick="tableColumnSort(this); changeTH(this);">
        veryLongLongHeader
      </th>
      <th onclick="tableColumnSort(this); changeTH(this);">
        header
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

On JS:

```
function changeTH(container){
   var ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
   var totalThs = ths.length;
   //reset all ths before set your new th style
   for (i = 0; i < totalThs; i++){
     ths[i].style.background = '#fff';
     ths[i].style.fontSize = 'inherit';
   }
   container.style.background = '#ccc';
   container.style.fontSize = '12px'; //or other size you prefer
}
```

The better way to do this is add all listeners inside a js file, it's more elegant, but my example works fine.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I couldn't get the other recommendations to work, but this gave me the idea to just create a css button and just assign the class with :hover option to my th element, and leaving my onclick to what it was. Pretty simple and straight forward with elegance. Maybe within the onclick I will use some jQuery to adjust the color until the sort completes. Thanks for the outside the box answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you set an element to `width: 100%` or `height: 100%`, it's relative to its parent element. So, if you're setting your button `width: 100%`, and you want it to be 100% of your header width, set a width (that's not in percentage) on the header and it'll respect it. Like this:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <button>shortHeader</button>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button>veryLongLongHeader</button>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button>header</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <button>shortHeader</button>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button>veryLongLongHeader</button>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button>header</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  width: 100px;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darienh/bmko56mL/).

Answer (score 0):

Make your buttons `display: block`.

```css
table, th, td { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #333; }
th button { display: block; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><button>DELETE</button></th>
      <th><button>PARTNO</button></th>
      <th><button>DLT</button></th>
      <th><button>TCOUNT</button></th>
      <th><button>TRANS</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td>3</td><td>20170315</td><td>1</td><td>R</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>3</td><td>20170315</td><td>1</td><td>R</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>3</td><td>20170315</td><td>1</td><td>R</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>3</td><td>20170315</td><td>1</td><td>R</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That didn't work. Just shows as the first picture did in my post.

Comment: Works just fine. I checked it with Chrome 57, Firefox 51, IE 11, and Edge 38/15. It would be better if you posted an [mcve] instead of pictures.